# If xx exist do yy

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS.
I'm trying to create a script to auto fill a form on a webpage by using Greasemonkey.

If the error code below exists on the page, I want my script to click "Back" button.

```
<div>
  <div id="registration_error" class="errBlock" style="color:Red;">
    <ul><li>Address is required.</li></ul>
</div>
```

I tried some codes (I don't know if correct or not, I made assumptions) with no success, including;

```
if(document.getElementById("registration_error).innerText.Contains("Address is required.")
{
 document.getElementsByClassName('btnRegister')[0].click();
}
```

also tried

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('errBlock').innerText.Contains("Address is required")

if ("#registration_error").innerText.Contains("Address is required")
```

etc etc
I tried many combinations to my knowledge. Clicking button works fine but can't figure out the if condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first snippet of code you tried is the closest to correct.

The first part, `document.getElementById("registration_error")`, is correct (except that you are missing a quotation mark on yours).

Then, you are trying to get the HTML code inside this `registration_error` div.  The correct way to do this is `.innerHTML`.  (`.innerText` isn't browser-compatible (didn't work in mine))

The last part where your checking to see if the HTML contains `"Address is required"` is wrong.  The right way to check if a bit of text is contained in a string is to use `"hello world".indexOf("llo")`.  This function will return the location of the string if found, or `-1` if the text is not contained in the string.

So, your final `if` statement looks like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("registration_error").innerHTML.indexOf("Address is required.") !== -1){
    document.getElementsByClassName('btnRegister')[0].click();
}
```

That should work for you.  Note that Javascript *is* case-sensitive, so make sure you get that right.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking your time to explain details and showing me the correct way to fix it. The code worked perfect!

Comment: `.innerText` most definitely exists just not recommended due to not being available in every browser.